# SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow email not updating

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Recently I have been experiencing a weird phenomenon with some of my list workflows in SharePoint Designer 2010.

1. I create a workflow in which some of the steps involve sending out emails. The workflow works fine.
2. After a couple of days I make some changes to the email texts (not the workflow), hit Save and then Publish.

Obviously at this stage the emails that are being sent out should contain the new text but funnily the old text is sent but in SharePoint Designer the new text is visible. When this happens the only option I have left is to recreate the workflow and attach the new workflow to the list which is a very cumbersome process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696221/1282079) and see if it solves your problem.

If you want to check it out more in depth, you would need to download something like [SharePoint Manager 2010](http://spm.codeplex.com/) and run it on the server to analyze the state of the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Email Action then save and publish workflow. Now check workflow after that Add the Email action at the same Place with New Email Body Content, finally save and publish.

Check may it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache and try. Below are the steps.

1. If Sharepoint Designer is open, close it
2. Open My Computer and enter
   '%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache' in address bar
3. Delete files and other folders in this location
4. Now go to this location '%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server
   Extensions\Cache' and delete all files and folders

Re publish the workflow. This may solve the issue.

The above steps are referred from http://luckytechshare.blogspot.in/2015/05/workflow-running-on-old-version.html